# C# COM Object not finding 3rd party DLL files

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, com, powerbuilder

COM Object problem.

I have three visual studio projects V1, V2, and V3.
I am using WPF/C# in Visual Studio 2015, on a WIndows 8 and Windows 7 platform.
V2 and V3 result in DLL files.

V1 is a WPF test application which calls methods in a class in V2

V2 is a class library from which there are calls to methods in a class in V3

V3 is a class library

All this works fine. Even when I define the V2 project to produce a COM object.
Project.Propeerties.Application.Assembly Info: "Make assembly COM-Visible" checked
Project.Propeerties.Build. Register for COM interop checked
Signing. Sign the assembly. Signed

(The V3 project is not defined as a COM object)

When I replace the test application V1 with another project (not defined in WPF/C#, but another non-managed language such as PowerBuilder), then I can still call up those methods which are exclusively in V2.

But, If the method in V2 calls a method in V3, then the program crashes. It cannot locate the V3.DLL file.

Annoyingly it works fine in the development environment with Visual Studio, Powerbuilder and their debuggers but not on a test platform where only the .EXE and DLL files are present.

I am using "Regasm.exe" to register the V2 com object in the test environment, which is not necessary in the development environment since Visual Studio does all that for me.

I have looked into manifest files, played with the PATH variables, placed the V3.DLL file here and there all without any joy.

Is it the case that V3.DLL must also be registered as a COM object? This is not what I want and may cause us problems if we have to go there.

John

Comment: This is quite normal, the CLR looks in two places for dependent assemblies.  First the GAC, next the same directory where the EXE is located.  Your V3 dll is no doubt in neither, it never is in a COM scenario.  The GAC is never a bad idea when you expose through COM, also solves its nasty versioning problems.  Or you'll have to help by implementing  AppDomain.AssemblyResolve in V2.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right path to a solution. 
I would just add that putting something in the GAC was not as straight forward as I had hoped.

Dragging DLL's (with strong names) into the virtual folder doesn't work for .Net Framework 4.0 and later. The GACUTIL.EXE program is [windows] target platform  specific. The version of the assembly is relevant, the version of the runtime is relevant and the GACUTIL was not as easy to locate as I was led to believe. And finally the GacUtil.exe is licenced software not for free distribution.

However my solution is now working fine. Thanks agains.